# how do you set the name of the file as data from a variable (in R)?

Tags: r, loops, csv, data-mining

how do you set the name of the file as data from a variable? e.g. creating the file in a for loop (so it wouldn't be overwritten when the next file is created with new data)

for example:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the parameter in write.table, do this

```
file = paste0("C:\\Users\\my-PC\\Dropbox\\Data mining\\", instruments, ".csv")
```

Comment: @Sam I think the line should be like this

write.table(train, file = paste0("C:\\Users\\my-PC\\Dropbox\\Data mining\\", instruments, ".csv"), sep = ",")

Comment: I recommend `file.path` function for use this code between Mac and Win without a bug.